# Codeigniter loading model from different subfolder

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

I'm facing one weird problem with my Codeigniter project.

I have two model files in the following paths:

```
models/public/Dish_model.php
models/admin/Dish_model.php
```

For front-end and back-end models respectively.

In the controller which is in the following path:

```
controllers/admin/Dish.php
```

I'm trying to load the admin area model file using:

```
$this->load->model('admin/dish_model');
```

But it is loading the public model file.

Even if I comment this line out the public model file still gets loaded.

This all happened suddenly it was working fine before and I haven't changed any of the mentioned files recently.

Any help?

Comment: How you know it is loading another model file? use alternative way. `$this->load->model('admin/dish_model', 'amodel');` and use like this`$this->amodel->method();`

Comment: I know because I tried calling a function from each one and only the one from the other model worked!

Comment: I've also tried your suggestion ... no difference :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else encounter the same issue.

In my case and after carefully following the execution path of the controller I found that the other model was being loaded by a library in the autoload list.

Removing that library from the autoload array fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

to call/load a model from its subdirectory or subfolder.

```
models/public/Dish_model.php
```

let's say in `Dish_model`

```
class Dish_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
    }
    public function the_method(){
       return 'return value';
    }
}
```

`models` it's a native ci model directory and `public` it's a subdirectory. so to load the `Dish_model` do this on controller

```
$this->load->model('public/Dish_model','DModel');
```

the `DModel` it is like an alias.
so to call the model from the controller is

```
echo $this->DModel->the_method();
```

and it will return `return value`
hope its help.